# How to fetch a list of JSON objects instead of list of IDs from a JSONB field when doing a SELECT statement in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables, **users** and **simulations**. The **users** table has a list of user details with an auto-increment ID field. The **simulations** table contains details of simulations along with a list of associated users. The `user_list` column in the simulations table is a `jsonb` field containing a list IDs of the associated users.

Samples of the two tables are given below:

**Table Name: users**

**Data:**

```
  ID       name          country       age
 ----      ------       ---------     -----
   1       Jason          USA          21
   2       William        England      40
   3       Jake           USA          34
   .
   .
   . 
   (total 100,000 rows)
```

**Table Name: simulations**

**Data:**

```
 ID   simulation_name     user_list       datetime
----  ---------------    ----------      ----------
 1      sample1           [1,2]         <some datetime>
 2      sample2           [5,6]         <some datetime>
 .
 .
 .
```

I am able to fetch data regarding simulations of a specific country using the following query

```
SELECT * from simulations
WHERE ARRAY(SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(user_list)::bigint)
      && ARRAY(SELECT id FROM users
               WHERE country = 'USA');
```

This gives the following response

```
 ID   simulation_name       datetime            user_list      
----  ---------------       ----------         ----------
 1      sample1           <some datetime>        [1,2]         
 2      sample4           <some datetime>       [1,9,12]      
 .
 .
 .
```

However, this is not exactly what I need. I need the `users_list` column to return not just IDs but a json object containing details of each user as well.
This is the kind of response I actually need:

```
 ID   simulation_name      datetime                                user_list
---  ----------------   --------------                            ------------
 1      sample1         <some datetime>     [{"id":1,"name":"Jason","country":"USA"},{"id":2,"name":"William","country":"England"}]
 .
 .
```

How do I replace user IDs with the actual details of the users as a list of JSON objects so as to get the above response?

(I know that this would have been much easier if I followed a many-to-many table structure but due to certain business requirements I have to follow this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join or correlated subquery to retrieve the related user details along with [`json_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) to aggregate the related user details in a json array as shown below.

You may also use `s.user_list @> u.id::text::jsonb` to determine whether a user exists in the list.

**Using join**

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.simulation_name,
    s.datetime ,
    json_agg(u.*) as user_list
FROM
    simulations s
INNER JOIN
    users u ON s.user_list @> u.id::text::jsonb AND
               u.country='USA' 
GROUP BY
    s.id,s.simulation_name,s.datetime;
```

| id | simulation_name | datetime | user_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sample1 | some datetime | [{"id":1,"name":"Jason","country":"USA","age":21}] |

---

**Using correlated query**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.simulation_name,
    s.datetime ,
    (
        SELECT json_agg(u.*)
        FROM users u
        WHERE s.user_list @> u.id::text::jsonb AND
              u.country='USA' 
    ) as user_list
FROM
    simulations s
) t
WHERE t.user_list IS NOT NULL;
```

| id | simulation_name | datetime | user_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sample1 | some datetime | [{"id":1,"name":"Jason","country":"USA","age":21}] |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p9y9pqHtZiC72Q6FimdXuL/1)

Let me know if either works for you.

Comment: I tried the JOIN approach and it works perfectly. I had tried a similar approach earlier but had got the typecasting part wrong so it wasn't working. Thanks :)